# Strange tab bar in my view - Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

please look at the following view

[image]

Everything was working fine but suddenly I noticed a strong behaviour, it's like another tab bar on my tab bar !

I might did something by mistake but I didn't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on the view controller icon [where the blue line is being dragged from in the below photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox0co.png) and went to the attributes instructor (4th tab from on the right) and changed the bottom bar simulated metrics to none. This got rid of it for me. Hope this helps !